# Java: I'd like a JLabel to respond to mouse events only sometimes. Is there a way to hide a mouse listener until wanted?

Tags: java, swing, mouse, listener

I see there are methods already built for adding and removing mouse listeners, I suppose I could add them and remove them as needed. I just wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Having my JLabel respond to all mouse events over it but sometimes do nothing isn't quite what I'm looking for, it would be nice if my Labels had the mouse listener only when I needed it to. Maybe this whole idea is just a weird approach.

Comment: Ca you tell us more about when it should respond to mouse events?

Comment: It's not such a problem to listen for events and decide to do nothing based on other factors

Comment: for better help sooner edit yoour question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated yout issue with MouseListener and JLabel, btw add / remove the listener is very good programing concept, but nobody knows in your case and without seeing runnable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You register the Listener once and for all; you don't turn it off and on.

You can code logic inside to only take action under certain conditions of your choosing.  As long as you make the information available that's needed for a decision your implementation should be fine.